# looking for MySQL failover and loadbalace setup for clusting

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, cluster, failovercluster, mysql-cluster

i have setup my clusting for 3 mysql servers, 1 master and 2 nodes what i need to do right now its setup a failover system and loadbalace setup.

Can sombardy link to a good article about that? i use newst Ubuntu 10.10 i mean, i can't remeber current, its soon here :P

i hobe to get help, i use mysql-cluster-server-5.1 if its help.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't have a big failover with just 1 master.. All your writes go to the master so if that fails your system is readonly.

What I do is run [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) and have a master/master setup but all writes go to 1 machine and if that machine fails the other master is setup as a "sorry server" and all writes now go there.

Answer (score 0):

I hope [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ha-overview.html) helps. Or this book looks interesting. If you get the [book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596807290), let me know if it is any good.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a combination of HAProxy and MMM

http://mysql-mmm.org/

HAProxy can load balance the reads between the two masters (with weighting) and then MMM will handle the management of failing over the primary in the case of it going down to provide the maximum uptime.